# Sort List<T> by reference

Tags: c#, sorting, reference, icomparer

I would like to sort a `List<T>` by reference. Why? I want to compare several lists and find which elements are unique to a given list. Sorting them first in some canonical fashion and then stepping through all lists simultaneously seems a good way to do this. This essentially means that I need to make aa `IComparer<T>` that returns a non-zero integer for different references (and is consistent). The order does have to mean anything, but just provide a fixed order for all `T` for at least the time it takes me to get the job done.

`GetHashCode` can return the same value for two different objects on a 64-bit system, so that is out as a way to do a comparison.

`IntPtr` from `AddrOfPinnedObject()` might work since it has the correct size, but I have to pin the object for the duration of the process.

Making a `Dictionary<T, long>` where the `long` is issued first-come first-served is what I'm going with now, but I want to know if there are better options. The hash lookup seems unnecessary.

What is the best way to define `ReferenceComparer<T> : IComparer<T>` to give me that fixed ordering?

Here is the dictionary implementation:

```
public class ReferenceComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private long nextAvailable = 0;
    private readonly Dictionary<T, long> objectToLong = new Dictionary<T, long>(new AsObjectEqualityComparer<T>());

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        long xLong;
        if (!objectToLong.TryGetValue(x, out xLong))
        {
            xLong = nextAvailable;
            objectToLong[x] = xLong;
            nextAvailable = nextAvailable + 1;
        }

        long yLong;
        if (!objectToLong.TryGetValue(y, out yLong))
        {
            yLong = nextAvailable;
            objectToLong[y] = yLong;
            nextAvailable = nextAvailable + 1;
        }

        return xLong.CompareTo(yLong);
    }
}
```

Comment: The dictionary idea sounds fine, as soon as you add `class` constraint to `T` (or better remove `T` and simply implement `IComparer<object>`), use correctly implemented reference equality comparer in the dictionary and fix the implementation bugs (`xLong` and `yLong` are not set inside the `if` blocks and should be).

Comment: Good catch on not setting `xLong`, `yLong`.

Comment: I meant, instead of your `ReferenceComparer<T> : IComparer<T>` it would be enough to implement `ReferenceComparer : IComparer<object>`. It could be used for any `List<T>` as soon as `T` is class (reference type). Inside the comparer you would use `Dictionary<object, long>` with special equality comparer similar to [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Objects/ObjectStateManager.cs,55f103aae513f5b0)

Comment: Yes. I did get that. I think it's a good idea. I assume the `class` constraint is just to make the name meaningful. It works for structs, but what to call it then?

Comment: You can't compare structs by reference anyway.

Comment: That is what I was implying by my previous comment.